# UIButton title expansion limits

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton, uilabel

I'm having a trouble for controlling the title expansion limits of `UIButton` with the `UIButtonConfiguration`. Here is the setup code of my button:

```swift
private lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()

    self.view.addSubview(btn)

    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, leading: 12.0, bottom: 1.0, trailing: 12.0)
        configuration.imagePadding = 12.0
        btn.configuration = configuration
    } else {
        btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -12, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return btn
}()
```

Out of curiousity, I wanted to test its behavior when the title is too long:

```swift
self.button.setTitle("DoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDoneDone", for: .normal)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
    self.button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 96.0),
    self.button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    self.button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
])
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JqFQ.png)

How can I adjust its content expansion limits? I want it to behave like pre iOS 15.0 UIButton title(truncating its label with 1 line)

I have tried to set `numberOfLines` to 1 and `lineBreakMode` to `.byTruncatingTail` for `UIButton`'s `titleLabel`. However it didn't make any difference.

Comment: That's kind of the point of the new style of buttons? It's not like the old style buttons are deprecated or anything. Feel free to use `UIButton`s without a configuration. :)

Comment: Actually I were using the old style setup. But when I tried to set image and content edge insets, xcode started to complain that they were deprecated after iOS 15.0, use the new configuration. Then here's the result ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Supposedly, setting an `attributedTitle` with a paragraph style that has `byTruncatingMiddle` as the line break mode should also work, but that didn't work for me. :( Perhaps you can try it?

Comment: I tried as you instructed. It also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's worth noting that the "deprecated" is a **warning** - not an **error**.

Second, also worth noting, the full message includes:

- 'imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: ***This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration***

which means, it is NOT ignored when NOT using `UIButtonConfiguration`.

Third, *as a general rule*, you will probably be happier using a single button type... as it will remain consistent in functionality and appearance across iOS versions.

So, for now, I would recommend just sticking with the "old-style" buttons.

---

That said, though, you *could* give this a try...

`UIButton` subclass:

```
class MyForcedSingleLineButton: UIButton {
    
    public var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if let tl = titleLabel {
            var r = tl.frame
            r.size.height = self.bounds.height
            r.origin.y = 0
            r.size.width = self.bounds.width - 24.0
            r.origin.x = 12.0
            tl.frame = r
            tl.numberOfLines = 1
            tl.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }
    }
    
}
```

Many "built-in" views / controls do a lot of work under-the-hood, and `UIButton` is no exception. UIKit will continuously "reset" the title label properties, so we're making our adjustments every time we get `layoutSubviews()`.

Here's a quick example controller - I'm creating eight buttons: two each of the four "new" styles, one with `.byTruncatingTail` and the other with `.byTruncatingMiddle`. Every button has the (full) title of *"This needs to truncate instead of wrapping onto multiple lines!"*:

```
class ButtonTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 20
        
        let t: String = "This needs to truncate instead of wrapping onto multiple lines!"
        
        let styles: [UIButton.Configuration] = [
            .plain(), .gray(), .tinted(), .filled()
        ]
        
        var btn: MyForcedSingleLineButton!
        
        // let's add two buttons of each Configuration style
        //  one with .byTruncatingTail
        //  one with .byTruncatingMiddle
        styles.forEach { style in
            
            var cfg = style
            cfg.title = t
            
            btn = MyForcedSingleLineButton()
            btn.configuration = cfg
            
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0).isActive = true
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128.0).isActive = true
            
            btn.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            
            stack.addArrangedSubview(btn)

            btn = MyForcedSingleLineButton()
            btn.configuration = cfg
            
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0).isActive = true
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128.0).isActive = true

            btn.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
            
            stack.addArrangedSubview(btn)
            
        }

        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

That custom `MyForcedSingleLineButton` subclass is (hopefully obviously) not complete... you'd want to adapt it using dynamic values to reflect custom insets, use of an image, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed alternative approach, that was the way I wished to do it. Additionally it'd be very good if Apple took care of this button behavior beforehand as the old-style setup.

Comment: @Murad - with the "old style" we had to jump through hoops to get an auto-sizing button with a multi-line title. No doubt, part of the "new style" design was intended to make that easy. Truncating a button title seems to be - in my experience - an "outlier" case. But, with enough feedback directly to Apple, it wouldn't surprise me if a future iOS version would add `numberOfLines` as a button configuration property.